# Diffusion in a harmonic potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion

I am just looking for the correct Ansatz to a one-dimensional diffusion equation with a harmonic potential.

Let $n(x,t)$ be the density of particles and $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}\alpha x²$ a potential.
Then the current density is
$$j(x,t)=-D\frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial x}-\sigma \left(-\vec\nabla_x  \Phi(x) \right)$$
with $D$ as diffusion coefficient and any kind of "conductivity" $\sigma$.
With the equation of continuity
$$\frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial j(x,t)}{\partial x}=0$$

one gets the inhomogeneous equation
$$\frac{\partial n(x,t)}{\partial t}-D \frac{\partial^2 j(x,t)}{\partial x^2}+\kappa=0$$
with a positive constant $\kappa$.

My only question is whether this reasoning is correct? If so, the rest would be solving the equation by standard method.

Comment: I think you're missing the differential $\mathrm{d}$ on the flux term (i.e., $\mathrm{d}j/\mathrm{d}x$ instead of $j/\mathrm{d}x$).

Answer (score 2):

Your result has something funny about it:
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}-D\color{red}{\frac{\partial j}{\partial x} }+\kappa=0 \tag{your result} $$
The $D$ and $\kappa$ both come from the definition of $j$, so you shouldn't have both of these values *and* the divergence of $\mathbf{j}$ in the result at the same time. Hence, you should be expecting something like
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}-D\color{blue}{\frac{\partial^2n}{\partial x^2}}+\kappa=0 \tag{expected result},$$
which has the diffusion term present.

The current density otherwise looks to be of the form of a [drift-diffusion equation](https://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/ayalew/node50.html) often seen in semiconductor physics.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the second derivative. I have to think again. I simply took the current density $j$  from the Drude model and replaced $E$ by $-\nabla \Phi$ and added this to the diffusion current $-D \nabla n$ which is perhaps too simple. But for now I want to leave this alone and write again when I am clearer.